# Nginx return `444` on deny

Tags: nginx, firewall

I have an `Nginx` instance where I only want to allow certain IP ranges:

```
allow 192.168.0.0/16;
deny all;
```

This works fine, however when denied, a `403` is returned.

I don't denied IPs to know I have a web server at all. However can I return `444` instead, aka drop the packet?

Comment: Use a firewall.

Comment: My question is how to achieve this with nginx...

Comment: You don't. nginx is not a firewall.

Comment: As terse as @MichaelHampton 's comment is, he's right. You don't want to burden nginx with the job of denying traffic that shouldn't be reaching it in the first place - that's exactly the job of a firewall and will reduce the load on nginx, freeing it up to do the job it's supposed to do. How about explaining why you want nginx to handle the denial of connections rather than a firewall? That might get you some better answers.

Answer (score 3):

actually you can use geo directive, also if and return directive to achieve what you mean. Here is configuration you need to use:

```
http{
    ...
    geo $remote_addr $allowed_trafic {
        default false;
        192.168.0.0/16 true;
    }
}
server {
    ...
    if ( $allowed_trafic = 'false'){
        return 444;
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

1. create file "ip.conf", then include to "nginx.conf"
2. The "ip.conf" should look like:

```
geo $bad_ip {
    192.168.0.0/16;
    10.0.0.0/16;
    default 1;
}
```

3. The "app.conf" file should look like:

```
location / {
        if ($bad_ip) {
            return 444;
        }
        proxy_pass http://app/;
}
```